# Powershell Array to comma separated string with Quotes

Tags: arrays, string, powershell

I have an array that I need to output to a comma separated string but I also need quotes "". Here is what I have.

```
$myArray = "file1.csv","file2.csv"
$a = ($myArray -join ",")
$a
```

The output for
`$a` 
ends up

```
file1.csv,file2.csv
```

My desired output is

```
"file1.csv","file2.csv"
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: `'"' + ($myArray -join '","') + '"'`

Comment: Write-Host "Comma separated string: $($arryOfStrings -join ', ')"

Answer (score 56, accepted):

Here you go:

```
[array]$myArray = '"file1.csv"','"file2.csv"'
[string]$a = $null

$a = $myArray -join ","

$a
```

Output:

```
"file1.csv","file2.csv"
```

You just have to get a way to escape the `"`. So, you can do it by putting around it `'`.

Comment: I do not recommend this method. Take a look at [Powershell 7 - Array to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276437/powershell-array-to-comma-separated-string-with-quotes/67395892#67395892) or [Earler versions of Powershell - Array to CSV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276437/powershell-array-to-comma-separated-string-with-quotes/46976697#46976697)

Answer (score 46):

I know this thread is old but here are other solutions

```
$myArray = "file1.csv","file2.csv"

# Solution with single quote
$a = "'$($myArray -join "','")'"
$a
# Result = 'file1.csv','file2.csv'

# Solution with double quotes
$b = '"{0}"' -f ($myArray -join '","')
$b
# Result = "file1.csv","file2.csv"
```

Comment: Super clean and works with outputted array, this is the best answer.

Comment: This is absolutely brilliant. Would you mind breaking down what is happening in the expression
$b = '"{0}"' -f ($myArray -join '","') please ? Thank you very much.

Comment: `$myArray -join '","'` result is `file1.csv","file2.csv`. Then the `-f` operator puts this result between double-quotes

Answer (score 13):

If using PowerShell Core (currently 7.1), you can use [Join-String](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/join-string?view=powershell-7.1)
This is not available in PowerShell 5.1

```
$myArray | Join-String -DoubleQuote -Separator ','
```

Output:

```
"file1.csv","file2.csv"
```

Answer (score 1):

### *One-line* solutions

Supposing there is an *array* or *list* inside `$myArray`.
Defined such as:

```bash
$myArray = @("one", "two")
```

We have two solutions:

1. Using **double-quotes ( " )** as separator:

   ```bash
   '"{0}"' -f ($myArray -join '","')
   ```

   Outputs:

   ```plain
   "one","two"
   ```
2. Using **single-quotes ( ' )** as separator:

   ```bash
   "'{0}'" -f ($myArray -join "','")
   ```

   Outputs:

   ```
   'one','two'
   ```

Comment: This is nice, but remember that if you try to join an *array* of numbers, like `$q =@(1,2,3)`, you can no longer use `-in` test. Example: `$p = @(1,2,3); $q = '{0}' -f ($p -join ','); 2 -in $p; 2 -in $q;` with output: `True, False`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a Join-String method that will work in older methods of PowerShell

```
function Join-String {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    Param(
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)] [string[]]$StringArray, 
        $Separator=",",
        [switch]$DoubleQuote=$false
    )
    BEGIN{
        $joinArray = [System.Collections.ArrayList]@()
    }
    PROCESS {
        foreach ($astring in $StringArray) {
            $joinArray.Add($astring) | Out-Null
        }
    }
    END {
        $Object = [PSCustomObject]@{}
        $count = 0;
        foreach ($aString in $joinArray) {
            
            $name = "ieo_$($count)"
            $Object | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name $name -Value $aString;
            $count = $count + 1;
        }
        $ObjectCsv = $Object | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter $separator
        $result = $ObjectCsv[1]
        if (-not $DoubleQuote) {
            $result = $result.Replace('","',",").TrimStart('"').TrimEnd('"')
        }
        return $result
    }
}
```

It can be invoked with array parameter or passthrough

```
Join-String @("file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt") -DoubleQuote
```

Output:

```
"file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt"
```

or as pass-thru:

```
@("file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt") | Join-String -DoubleQuote
```

Output:

```
"file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt"
```

Without -DoubleQuote

```
@("file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt") | Join-String
```

Output:

```
file1.txt,file2.txt,file3.txt
```

or with a custom separator, say a semicolon

```
@("file1.txt","file2.txt","file3.txt") | Join-String -DoubleQuote -Separator ";"
```

Output:

```
"file1.txt";"file2.txt";"file3.txt"
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a slight addition to @Jason S's answer, adding a carriage return (and line feed - a Windows thing):

```
$myArray | Join-String -DoubleQuote -Separator `r`n
```

And with the comma:

```
$myArray | Join-String -DoubleQuote -Separator ",`r`n"
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the requirement to double-quote only strings that contain **whitespace**.

```sh
$myArray = 'foo', 'b ar', "ba`tz" 
$myArray -replace '.*\s.*', '"$0"' -join ','
```

**Output:**

```text
foo,"b ar","ba  z"
```

This takes advantage of the fact that the RegEx-based `-replace` operator can take an array as the LHS operand. In this case it outputs a new array with any replacements done.

The RegEx pattern `.*\s.*` matches any string that contains at least one whitespace character. The `.*` match any surrounding characters, so the whole input string will be matched, if it contains a whitespace. The replacement pattern `"$0"` then quotes the whole match. If there is no match, the input string will be passed on without quoting.

Finally, `-join` joins the quoted strings.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one, using the builtin foreach method, and escaping doublequotes with backquotes:

```
$myarray = echo file1.csv file2.csv
$myarray.ForEach{"`"$_`""} -join ','

"file1.csv","file2.csv"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$array = @(0,1,2,3,4,5)
"@($('"' + ($array -join '","') + '"'))"
```

output:

```
@("0","1","2","3","4","5")
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?