# How to add double quotes to each array element when joining array of strings in powershell

Tags: powershell

I'm using Powershell 5. I have a bunch of pdfs in my current working directory. I collect
and join their names as follows:

`$(get-childitem *.pdf).name -join " "`

The result is as follows:

`pdf1.pdf pdf2.pdf pdf3.pdf`

However, I need something like this:

`"pdf1.pdf" "pdf2.pdf" "pdf3.pdf"`

How do I get double quotes around each array element?

Comment: join using `'" "'` as delimiter and add a `"` at the end and begining of the result

Comment: That's a bit clumsy, but it works

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Powershell Array to comma separated string with Quotes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39276437/powershell-array-to-comma-separated-string-with-quotes)

Comment: @SagePourpre The useful answers in that question all make use of `join-string` which is a newer command, not available to Powershell 5. I'm using powershell 5 and `join-string` is not available to me

Comment: @user32882 how is it clumsy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Cid says, this is one way to do it:

`'"' + $($(get-childitem *.pdf).name -join '" "') + '"'`

Comment: You don't need your `$` signs there... It is only required if you are within an inline string. Parenthesis will work just fine. It make it a tad more clean IMO.  Another way to write this completely would be to use the string format `-f` operator and do it like this `  '"{0}"' -f ((Get-ChildItem *.pdf).Name -join '" "')`